# sql query to import data from excel 2003-2007 to sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

am trying to import data from excel to sql server table in a database
my sql server is sql server 2014
i tried the following code. but i got the error.please help me to solve this
my code is

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sheet1$ 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\SHANI MATHEW\Downloads\Feed_Labels_test.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

i got the following error
Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 0):

Often times you are better off converting the excel files you would like to import into Comma Seperated Files. Then just import the CSV's into SQL using Bulk Insert or Import\Export wizard built into SQL Server.

Import\Export wizard:
[Import\Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

Bulk Insert:
[Bulk Insert Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)

Comment: i want excel to import,not csv.

Comment: Import\Export Wizard and Integration Services support Excel files. The jet driver is extremely slow import method. If you are importing a significant number of rows this will be a very slow operation to due the limitations of JET. the JET driver is very old and has other issues as well.

Comment: Sir, am not much familiar with ms sql queires.can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine you are running the above query have Microsoft Access installed? It is required for the above command to work because the JET driver is not built into SQL Server. See the following image from MSDN on the code you are running:[image]

See Article for more information on OpenRowSet:
[OpenRowSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)

Comment: am using sql server 2014